# Removing barriers from a QuantumCircuit object in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, transpile

I find barriers useful for visualization purposes, naturally it helps observing a circuit that is separated to some logical segments than just watching a mixture of gates and qubits.

However, before transpiling I would love to remove the barriers to avoid possible inefficiencies that can be caused by the presence of the barriers.

I have tried to use [`qiskit.transpiler.RemoveBarriers`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.RemoveBarriers.html) as in the example inside the link, and the following behavior occurs:

1. The barriers seem to be deleted from the `QuantumCircuit` object - verified by drawing using `QuantumCircuit.draw`, and by examining the content of the `QuantumCircuit.__dict__` attribute.
2. After transpiling the barriers are back again inside the transpiled `QuantumCircuit` object returned by the function `transpile`, along with the inefficiencies caused by the barriers which I tried to avoid in the first place.

Is there any simple way to get rid of barriers? Am I misunderstanding the functionality of `RemoveBarriers`?

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

I am adding a debugging piece of code:

```
print(f"operator.count_ops() = {operator.count_ops()}")

no_baerriers_operator = RemoveBarriers()(operator)
print(f"no_baerriers_operator.count_ops() = {no_baerriers_operator.count_ops()}")

transpiled_operator = transpile(no_baerriers_operator, **transpile_kwargs)
print(f"transpiled_operator.count_ops() = {transpiled_operator.count_ops()}")

print(f"transpile_kwargs = {transpile_kwargs}")
```

And its output:

```
operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('barrier', 3), ('([2] == [3])', 1), ('([0] == [1])', 1), ('ccx', 1), ('Uncomputation', 1)]) 

no_baerriers_operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('([2] == [3])', 1), ('([0] == [1])', 1), ('ccx', 1), ('Uncomputation', 1)]) 

transpiled_operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('cx', 14), ('u', 12), ('barrier', 2)])

transpile_kwargs = {'basis_gates': ['u', 'cx'], 'optimization_level': 3}
```

It can be seen, somewhat strangely, that in the original `QuantumCiruit` object (i.e `operator`) there are 3 barriers, then they vanish after using `RemoveBarriers` (no barriers in `no_barriers_operator`), and finally 2 barriers are back to `transpiled_operator` arfter transpilation.

The custom gates in `operator` don't contain any barriers.

Comment: It seems that you are doing something wrong because `RemoveBarriers` should work. Can you add your code here?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have edited the original post with a code example.

Comment: I got the output:
`operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('barrier', 3), ('cx', 2), ('h', 1)])`
`no_baerriers_operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('cx', 2), ('h', 1)])`
`transpiled_operator.count_ops() = OrderedDict([('u', 2)])`

Comment: I see. When I try an isolated exmaple like yours myself, it also works. So I guess it has something to do with the construction of `operator` (`operator` is an object that inherits from `QuantumCircuit`). Do you have any idea what might cause this issue? Adding the source code of `operator` here is infeasible.. I can send it to you via a private channel if it's possible.

Comment: I'm available on Qiskit's [Slack channel](https://qiskit.slack.com) (same username)

Comment: What are  `[0]==[1]` and `[2]==[3]`? Are they barriers with these names? If so this could be a bug that the RemoveBarrier only works with instructions of name `barrier`.

Comment: Thanks, @JunyeHuang, but @Egretta.Thula already solved the issue for me on Slack. The problem was with the `Uncomputation` block that contained barriers within it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, how to use `RemoveBarriers`:

```
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import RemoveBarriers
rb = RemoveBarriers()
circuit_out = rb(circuit_in)
```

This eliminates the barriers that are visible in the circuit. That is, if an instruction contains barriers as part of its decomposition, it wont be removed.